# There is a function to shorten nicely a string to one, two or three letters

Tags: javascript

There is a nice function/lib etc. to shorten **nicely** a string (like ios circle contact but more evolved)?

For example :

- John Doe -> JD
- My board -> Mb
- Something very long -> Svl
- My Very long board -> MVl
- Dash-board -> Db
- title -> t
- Title -> T
- JohnDoe -> JD
- John_Doe -> JD
- etc............................

I really can write it by myself each case I **can** see, but I'm looking for something nice and maybe more **clever** that my example (omit article for more than 3 words, omit dash if more than 3 words etc.).

Precision : the **nice** is my question. I'm looking for a library like stringjs.com/underscorejs (normalize, capitalize, slugify...) or a simple function but with a nice shorten method.

For the moment, I use this piece of code (update w/terabaud answer, thx dude) :

```js
function shortener(label) {
            //http://www.ranks.nl/stopwords
            var stopWords = "alors au aucuns aussi autre avant avec avoir bon car "
                + "ce cela ces ceux chaque ci comme comment dans des du "
                + "dedans dehors depuis deux devrait doit donc dos droite "
                + "début elle elles en encore essai est et eu fait faites "
                + "fois font force haut hors ici il ils je juste la le les "
                + "leur là ma maintenant mais mes mine moins mon mot même "
                + "ni nommés notre nous nouveaux ou où par parce parole "
                + "pas personnes peut peu pièce plupart pour pourquoi quand "
                + "que quel quelle quelles quels qui sa sans ses seulement "
                + "si sien son sont sous soyez sujet sur ta tandis tellement "
                + "tels tes ton tous tout trop très tu valeur voie voient "
                + "vont votre vous vu ça étaient état étions été être";

            var articles = stopWords.split(' ');

            return (label || "")
                .replace(/[A-Z]/g, " $&") // add space before each capital
                .replace(/[_\-']/g, " ") // replace _ - with spaces
                .split(" ")
                .filter(function (word) {
                    return word !== ""
                })
                .map(function (word, idx, arr) {
                    // return the first letter of each word
                    // if there are more than 2 words, omit articles
                    return (arr.length > 2 && articles.indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) > -1) ? "" : word[0];
                }).join("").slice(0, 3);
 
  };
    ["John Doe", "My board", "Something very long", "My Very long board", "Dash-board", "title", "Title", "JohnDoe","avec unwanted Words", "John_Doe"].forEach(function(str) {
      document.body.innerHTML += shortener(str) + '<br>';
    });
```

Comment: "*I really can write it by myself*" — go for it, when you have problems (that can be reproduced), *that's* when you should come back and ask us for help.

Comment: Please show us some effort. It might have been better if you posted your question as a challenge to find the shortest/nicest solution, at codegolf.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple way to do this. Try something like this:

```js
var articles = ["the", "a", "an"];

function shorten(str) {
  return (str || "")
    .replace(/[A-Z]/g, " $&") // add space before each capital
    .replace(/[_\-]/g, " ") // replace _ - with spaces
    .split(" ")
    .filter(function (word) { return word !== "" })
    .map(function(word, idx, arr) {
      // return the first letter of each word
      // if there are more than 3 words, omit articles
      return arr.length > 3 &&
        articles.indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) > -1 ?
        "" : word[0];
    }).join("").slice(0, 3);
}

["John Doe", "My board", 
 "Something very long", 
 "My Very long board",
 "Dash-board", 
 "title", 
 "Title", 
 "JohnDoe", 
 "John_Doe"].forEach(function(title) {
  document.body.innerHTML += shorten(title) + '<br>';
});
```

Comment: I like the use of map :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use regex in this order:

1. put space before any capital
2. change special character to space
3. remove all letter after the first letter in every word
4. remove all space

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want: please comment below

```
"My Very Long Board".split(' ').map(function(word){
 return word[0];
}).join('').slice(0, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `indexOf` on the variable that stores the `String`, to find:

The first three instances of a space, a capital letter or a dash.

Those three letters would give you a pretty good shortening.